# How to use ng-repeat scope inside another ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an array of objects:

```
expMonthByCat: 
    {Food: [some values],
     Clothing: [some values]
    }
```

I have a table that looks like:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="category in labels">
    <th scope="row">{{category}}</th>
    <td data-ng-repeat="expCat in expMonthByCat">{{expCat}}</td>
</tr>
```

I need to pass `category` in `<td data-ng-repeat="expCat in expMonthByCat">` because category contains Food, Clothing, and other keys I have inside expMonthByCat.

I tried
`<td data-ng-repeat="expCat in expMonthByCat.category">`
and
`<td data-ng-repeat="expCat in expMonthByCat">{{expCat.category}}</td>`
but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me out? Thanks!

EDIT

So the output of `<td data-ng-repeat="expCat in expMonthByCat track by $index">` is:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdB8p.png)

Where as the output of `<td data-ng-repeat="expCat in expMonthByCat.Food track by $index">{{expCat}}</td>` is:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEUJt.png)

How can I get the table to display its respective values?

My JS code:

```
$scope.expMonthByCat = {};
for (z = 0; z < $scope.labels.length; z++) {
    $scope.expMonthByCat[$scope.labels[z]] = new Array(12);
    for (x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
         $scope.expMonthByCat[$scope.labels[z]][x] = 0;
    }
}

for (x = 0; x < 12; x++){
    for (i = 0; i < response.data[2].length; i++) {
        $scope.labels.forEach(function (k) {
            if(response.data[2][i].category == k){
                if (response.data[2][i].expMonth == x + 1 && response.data[2][i].expYear == currentYear){
                    var expByCat = response.data[2][i].expAmount;
                    $scope.expMonthByCat[k][x] = parseFloat(Number(expByCat).toFixed(2));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="cat in labels">
    <th scope="row">{{cat}}</th>
    <td data-ng-repeat="expCat in expMonthByCat[cat]">{{expCat}}</td>
</tr>
```

Check the working demo:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1x269Ljc/5/)

Comment: LIFE SAVER! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `ng-repeat` on one table row to map all the headers in the table then from there we will need nested `ng-repeat` to map all the items that belong to that category. You can use `data-ng-repeat="(key,val) in labels"` to get the `key` of the labels.

```js
angular.module('notesApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.expMonthByCat = {
      Food: ['cake', 'burger'],
      Clothing: ['jeans', 't-shirt']
    }
    $scope.labels = Object.keys($scope.expMonthByCat);
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' ng-app="notesApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" data-ng-repeat="category in labels">{{category}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="(key,val) in labels">
    <td data-ng-repeat="expCat in expMonthByCat">{{expCat[key]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```